# Less custom function for :first-letter uppercase

Tags: css, less, scss-mixins, less-mixins

I'm looking for a way to create a custom mixin less function that would act as follows:

```
.my-class {
  ... .FirstLetterUppercase();
}
```

And that would transpile to:

```
.my-class {
  ...
}

.my-class:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Is that possible with less ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```css
.FirstLetterUppercase() {
  &:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

.my-class {
  .FirstLetterUppercase();
}
```

[More information about mixins](http://lesscss.org/#mixins)
[More information about nesting, pseudo-selectors and the ampersand](http://lesscss.org/#nesting)

Comment: Would add parentheses around the .FirstLetterUppercase so its not included in the output. 
Maybe add a bit about that this is called a mixin and link to the less documentation?

Comment: Awesome thank you! It may seem simple but for me the mixins documentation was not that obvious to understand (I was missing the ampersand indeed)

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt I thought that too - to be fair I had a guess at it as you can do something similar with sass and my first attempt worked in a less compiler (although I didn't know adding the parenthesis would mean it didn't output the original style)